# SVN Merge of Moved Source Code Files

Tags: svn, merge

I feel like I have the simplest use case in the world with SVN:

- I have a file, `Test.java` in `trunk` of SVN.
- I branch `trunk` to `dev-branch`.
- I move `Test.java` into `com/mycompany` folder in `trunk`.
- I change `Test.java` in `dev-branch`.
- I merge `dev-branch` to `trunk`.
- Tree conflict results.

Why, oh why, can't SVN handle this? Are we doing something wrong? This feels like it should be easy and yet every engineer at my company is stymied.

Looking for SVN-oriented answers here (not 'move to git', etc).

Comment: Try doing an SVN update on dev-branch before doing the merge.

Comment: I'm merging the dev branch into trunk using the following notation: svn merge url-of-dev-branch -r rev1:rev2 .

Comment: Try doing the SVN update, then use the higher revision number as rev1.

Comment: If you mean to do an svn update on trunk, I did that.

Comment: No.  Do the SVN update on the branch.

Comment: If the SVN update doesn't work, check out the trunk, apply your changes to the trunk, commit the trunk, and delete the branch.

Comment: Why would that help? I'm merging the branch into trunk. Branch is a remote URL so it ought to be up to date by definition. The only local folder I have is trunk and I made sure it was up to date before performing the merge.

Comment: I think @GilbertLeBlanc meant to merge the trunk to branch first which sounds like exactly the same problem—just in reverse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In SVN a move is a delete and an add. When you merged in the branch it would do the add part of your move, but it couldn't do the delete because of the conflict. You now have to resolve the conflict manually by

1. Copying your `Test.java` to `com/mycompany/Test.java`, overwriting the old one. That resolves the conflict with that file.
2. Delete the `Test.java` file from the old place. That is the manual way to do the delete part of the change set that SVN couldn't do when you did your merge. Use the `svn delete Test.java` command.
3. Tell SVN the conflict is resolved and that your working directory is correct with `svn resolve --accept working .` The dot at the end is for the current directory
4. Tell SVN that the `Test.java` file's conflict is also resolved with `svn resolve --accept working Test.java`

Then you can commit your merged version and you are back in sync with the repository.

Comment: That was what one of the engineers pointed out today in our conversation. It is unfortunate. Surely this problem isn't intractable. Are there any plans in svn to support a true svn move whose implementation is t to delete and then add?

Comment: It's hopeless. From the svn docs: 'A common desire is to refactor source code, especially in Java-based software projects. Files and directories are shuffled around and renamed, often causing great disruption to everyone working on the project. Sounds like a perfect case to use a branch, doesn't it? Just create a branch, shuffle things around, and then merge the branch back to the trunk, right?

Alas, this scenario doesn't work so well right now and is considered one of Subversion's current weak spots.'

Comment: Actually a `mv` is a `cp` and an `rm`

Answer (score 0):

In SVN 1.14, this merge should work fine. SVN will be able to detect the moved folder in trunk. So simply doing a merge would have been fine.

But if this is not the case, the alternative would be to merge the trunk 'tree change' into the branch first and then merge the branch into trunk again. So basically you align the branch with the newest changes in trunk (so the folder would have been created and the file moved into it), and then only merge back to trunk.